# How to unit test a file upload in Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing

I want to test a view that accepts .zip file as request.
So far, I tried this:

```
def test_upload_zip(self):
    with open('zip_file.zip', 'rb') as file:
        response = self.client.post(reverse(self.url), {'zip_file': file}, format='multipart')
```

The data I am getting at the view when I do `print(request.data)` is:

```
<QueryDict: {'zip_file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: zip_file.zip (application/zip)>]}>
```

But, for my actual request I want data in multipart like this:

```
<QueryDict: {'zip_file': ['data:application/zip;base64,UEsDBBQAAAAIAK1xmF................AAAA=']}>
```

In real request, I am not sending any `content-type` from my frontend. When I tried to put `content_type='multipart/form-data` in my test like this:

```
def test_upload_zip(self):
    with open('zip_file.zip', 'rb') as file:
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse(self.url), {'zip_file': file}, content_type='multipart/form-data'
        )
```

I got this error:

```
django.http.multipartparser.MultiPartParserError: Invalid boundary in multipart: None
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get the desired data in my `request.data`?